# Print the total of one field only once

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Hello I have a question on this query, my problem is that in this query I have to print the total of each chapter, but I have to do it only when the description changes, I try to explain with a diagram,how do I add a field with the addition of 1,2,3 only at the end of each description:

```
Descrizione                            Totale                TotaleCapitolo         DescrizioneDis

descrizione di prova                                       ------1----------             ---------------

                                                           -------2---------             ---------------

                                      SUM(1,2,3)          -------3---------             ---------------

descrizione di prova 2                                    ----------------            -----
```

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT 

CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Capitolo.Descrizione order by Capitolo.Descrizione) = 1 THEN Capitolo.Descrizione ELSE '' END AS 'Descrizione',

SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario as TotaleCapitolo,SottoCapitolo.Descrizione as DescrizioneDis, SottoCapitolo.Immagine, SottoCapitolo.DescrizioneEstesa, SottoCapitolo.Quantita, ROUND(((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeMargine) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeUtile) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali)), 0) as CostoUnitario FROM Preventivo inner join Capitolo on Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo inner join SottoCapitolo on SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo  where Preventivo.IdPreventivo='7' order by Capitolo.Descrizione
```

**QUERY RUN:**

[image]

**After query**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with C# or visual studio. This is a SQL question. Please also tag the question with the server you're using (It looks like SQL Server)

Comment: I was wrong, I adjusted @Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you further

**Update**

DescrizioneDis is on the third column, Immagine on the fourth.

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (Descrizione VARCHAR(255), Totale DECIMAL(18,6), DescrizioneDis VARCHAR(255), Immagine VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @T 
VALUES 
    ('descrizione di prova', 102.40, 'Tastiera ...', 'I:\So...'),
    ('descrizione di prova', 176.076, 'Echo 927 ...', 'I:\So...'),
    ('descrizione di prova', 32.03, 'CASS IP55 ...', '0'),
    ('descrizione di prova 2', 330.39, 'Accoppiatore ...', 'I:\So...')

SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Descrizione order by a.Descrizione) = 1 THEN a.Descrizione ELSE '' END AS Descrizione, 
    a.Totale, a.DescrizioneDis
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS d, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Descrizione order by Descrizione) AS r, Descrizione, Totale, DescrizioneDis, Immagine
    FROM @T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 0, Descrizione, SUM(Totale), '', ''
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY Descrizione
    ) AS a
ORDER BY a.Descrizione, a.d
```

Result

```
+----------------------+-----------+---------------+---------+
|Descrizione           |Totale     |DescrizioneDis |Immagine |
+----------------------+-----------+---------------+---------+
|descrizione di prova  |102.400000 |Tastiera ...   |I:\So... |
|                      |176.076000 |Echo 927 ...   |I:\So... |
|                      |32.030000  |CASS IP55 ...  |0        |
|                      |310.506000 |               |         |
|descrizione di prova 2|330.390000 |Accoppiatore ..|I:\So... |
|                      |330.390000 |               |         |
+----------------------+-----------+---------------+---------+
```

Please specify further if this is not the desired output.

Comment: i have try but it don't run!

Comment: What version of sql server are you running? I've tested this on SQL 2012 and it works. This will also work on SQL 2008.

Comment: my version is sql server 2014

Comment: strange... what error do you get? I can't imagine this won't work on SQL 2014. I've just executed this again without any problem.

Comment: I double checked I had some problems I, as your query works, but I do not see the values (DescrizioneDis, Immagine, ......) that there were in my query, I added the image of your above query

Comment: I've updated my post, DescrizioneDis was already selected. Please specify further if this is not the desired output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138099/discussion-between-riccardo-pirani-and-kevin).